# VideoView does not cover whole screen while playing videos in Android

Tags: android, media-player

I have developed a media player using VideoView for playing videos. It works fine but it has an issue that there is a white space at bottom of playing video. You can check my code and screen shot of the player. Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/video_view" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
        `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work, it will stretch your video to fill all the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoViewRelative"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```